# Requiring unknown module react/lib/ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native

Run command: `node ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android`
or `react-native run-android`

I got the error "Requiring unknown module react/lib/ReactNative"
trace:

```
E/unknown:React: Exception in native call from JS
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: Requiring unknown module "react/lib/ReactNative". (index.android.bundle:2)
              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:37)
              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:177)
              at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl$4.call(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:888)
              at com.facebook.react.XReactInstanceManagerImpl$4.call(XReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:881)
              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$1.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:74)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

---

"babel-preset-react-native": 1.9.2

"react": "^15.4.1"

"react-native": "^0.31.0"

EDIT:

I uploaded the whole [verbose Android Monitor output here](http://textuploader.com/d0ooi):

It actually has a lot of warnings suspiciously related but it is too hard for me to relate, such as:

1) first saying

```
W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry
```

2) then saying:

```
  W/unknown:React: Packager connection already open, nooping.
        W/unknown:React: Inspector connection already open, nooping.
```

3)  also a list of:

```
  W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

could it be related to hot-reloading as suggested below?

Requiring unknown module "react-native". #6753
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6753